# os.open vs open, what to use

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I'm new to python and, looking at the docs, saw that there are at least two ways of opening a file for access `os.open` and `open`. What is the difference between `os.open` and `open`?

When should I use `os.open`?

When should I use `open`?

Comment: Duplicate aside, why wouldn't you just read the documentation for both? That's what it's for.

Comment: I think this question is about using an advanced IDE :) It tells you that open is not defined, and that `import os` is not required.  Trying to fix it via "os.open" causes the wrong open function to be called (but fixes the two warnings.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [documentation of `os.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open):

> **Note:** This function is intended for low-level I/O. For normal usage, use the built-in function open(), which returns a file object with read() and write() methods (and many more). To wrap a file descriptor in a file object, use fdopen().