# os module not opening a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

Using the Python `os` Module, it is not opening this File (`bouncpass.txt`). When I run the code, nothing appears, I don't get no error or nothing. What is wrong with the below code?

```
import os

bouncfile = os.open('C:\\hoopers\\pickup\\towns\\bouncpass.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
```

Comment: That code will print nothing if it is correct and no error. Can you do print(bouncfile) and see?

Comment: Or better yet run it in the REPL (IPython)

Comment: What do you mean, "nothing appears"? You opened a file, but then what? Are you trying to read from it?

Comment: `os.open` does not open the file in some default text editor, if that's what you are expecting.

Comment: If you don't know what to do with `bouncfile`, then you probably want to use `open`, not `os.open`.

Comment: you can use simple open() method to openfile. This code has no error.

Comment: Hello , thankyou for the responses.  I was thinking that when opening the file, it would actually open up the file automatically on my desktop. Are you guys saying that in order to do this, you would have to "read" the file as well ?

Comment: mathtick, when i print(bouncfile), it produces the number 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
bouncfile = os.open('C:\\hoopers\\pickup\\towns\\bouncpass.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
str = os.read(bouncfile, os.path.getsize(bouncfile))
print(str.decode())
```

with `os.open()` file you need to use `os.read()` to read the content of file. I use dummy file so check ouptut screen
[image]

```
bouncfile = open('some.txt', 'r')
for val in bouncfile.readlines():
    print(val.rstrip())
```

you can use simple `open()` method to open file and you don't need read method to read content file with simple `open()` method.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or text output, include them as text. Also, note that you should always use the `open` function except if you have a good reason to use `os.open` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051249/os-open-vs-open-what-to-use). If you want to read a whole file, use the `read` method of the file object. Note also that `for line in f.readlines():` is an anti-pattern in Python, as it uselessly loads the whole file before iterating on the lines, while `for line in f:` will also iterate on the lines, but lazily.

Comment: ah, i see, this is another way of scrapping. Very good to know. thanks.  As i  mentioned in new comment i made above i was thinking that by using os.open, it could actually open the file on my computer automatically.

Comment: if you find the solution to your problem you can mark it as answer. Thanks and we are here to explain you everything where you got stuck while learning

Answer (score 0):

There may be a reason you are choosing os over open().

But as M. Twarog mentioned, you can bypass the need of the `os` library to open and read files by using the `open()` built-in method in python.

Just for additional info, another way of using `open()` is by using the `with` keyword in Python.

```
with open('\path\to\text', 'r') as f:
    info = f.read()
```

[What is the python keyword "with" used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)